Confusion about the Lefschetz standard conjectures for abelian varieties in the integral setting
Let $(A,\theta)$ be a principally polarized abelian variety of dimension $d$ over a number field $k$. By the hard Lefschetz theorem
$$H^2(A,\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}) \xrightarrow{\theta^{d-2}} H^{2d-2}(A,\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}(d-1))$$
is an isomorphism. We can also consider the integral hard Lefschetz map
$$H^2(A,\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}) \xrightarrow{\theta^{d-2}/(d-2)!} H^{2d-2}(A,\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}(d-1))$$
which cannot be an isomorphism if the minimal class $\theta^{d-1}/(d-1)! \in H^{2d-2}(A,\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}(d-1))$ is algebraic, otherwise there would exist some cycle $Z \in H^2(A,\mathbb{Z}_{\ell})$ such that $Z \cup \theta^{d-2}/(d-2)! = \theta^{d-1}/(d-1)!$, implying that $Z = \theta/(d-1)$, which is impossible if $\ell | (d-1)$. Note that I have used the fact that the integral hard Lefschetz map is injective, since the $\ell$-adic cohomology of abelian varieties is torsion-free.
However, the Lefschetz standard conjecture seems to imply that the inverse to $\_ \cup \theta^{d-2}$ is induced by a correspondence $\phi \in Ch^2(A \times A)$, at least this is claimed in the proof of Theorem $1.2$ of "The motive of the Fano surface of lines" (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1631073X16301145#br0110).
Would this correspondence $\phi$ not provide an inverse to the integral hard Lefschetz map, thus giving us a contradiction?

$\phi$ would provide an inverse to $,\cup, \theta ^{d-2}$, not to $, \cup, \theta ^{d-2}/(d-2)!$.

@abx would this not also be an inverse integrally then? Would that not be a contradiction when $\cup \theta^{d-2}$ is not an isomorphism integrally?

Oh, I see the problem. The Lefschetz standard conjecture uses rational coefficients : $\phi$ lives in $CH^2(A\times A)\otimes \Bbb{Q}$. (I suppose this is what Diaz'notation means, or it is a typo).

@abx ohh that would explain everything, thanks!
